# Root no longer root

Tags: 2.2-froyo, nexus-one, root-access, unrooting

I rooted my nexus one and successfully used a lot of root-only apps. But one day all these apps stopped working, saying I don't have root. Terminal emulator says "permission denied" for everything again, as if I wasn't root. But unlocked lock is still showed at startup. How would I fix that? I don't want to root again, because I will have to do a large backup then.

Comment: Are you stock or do you have a custom ROM?  And if the latter, which one?

Comment: Stock, not custom. Just rooted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you by chance have an automatic OTA update?  That would do it.

Comment: Probably yes. Do I need to root it again? Or what?

Comment: Yes,if you updated, you have to root it again.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid unrooting after OTA update,

1. Open SuperSU
2. Go to Settings
3. Enable Pro (you have to purchase the SuperSU Pro from PlayStore)
4. Enable Survival Mode